# How to configure file as a test file in sonarqube?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm using the `sonar-generic-coverage-plugin-1.2.jar`. In my xml I have the following line

```
<file path="src/assets/test/unit/tests/controllers/controller.coffee">
```

This file is part of my sonarqube analysis and is indexed - I can view it in sonar with its violations etc.

When running the generic coverage plugin, I do get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line 2 of report test/unittest.xml refers to a file which is not configured as a test file: src/assets/test/unit/tests/controllers/controller.coffee
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:172)
at org.sonar.plugins.coverage.generic.ReportParser.parseFiles(ReportParser.java:129)
at org.sonar.plugins.coverage.generic.ReportParser.parseRootNode(ReportParser.java:106)
at org.sonar.plugins.coverage.generic.ReportParser.access$000(ReportParser.java:44)
at org.sonar.plugins.coverage.generic.ReportParser$1.stream(ReportParser.java:93)
```

So how do I define the file as `a test file` ?

The coffee files get analysed by my own plugin, do I need to set something so that sonarqube can handle them as test files (or `InputFile.Type.MAIN` according to the generic plugin code) ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself thanks to this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/v5Z0PNxGkto

The problem is that the test files was part of the src directory. When moving it into the defined test directory, the import is successful